# Create SQL Server database at runtime from existing database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have SQL Server database with tables; I want to create the same database but empty on another machine.

I have written creation code in an EXE application and run it on client PC. But sometimes, I want to update it and recheck with my eyes all my code if I make any change.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Screenshot of my database:

[image]

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestCreateDataBase
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string ServerName;
        private string ServerConnectionString;
        private string DataBaseName="PulserDb";
        private string connstr;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private bool CreateTable(string Query)
        {
            using (SqlConnection tmpConn = new SqlConnection(connstr))
            {
                try
                {
                    tmpConn.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Query, tmpConn))
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = CurrentCursor;
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    tmpConn.Close();
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        private bool CreateDatabase()
        {
            string sqlCreateDBQuery;
            sqlCreateDBQuery = $"CREATE DATABASE {DataBaseName}";

            using (SqlConnection tmpConn = new SqlConnection(ServerConnectionString))
            {
                tmpConn.Open();
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCreateDBQuery, tmpConn);
                try
                {
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = CurrentCursor;
                    MessageBox.Show("Database has been created successfully!",
                                      "Create Database", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                                  MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor;
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = CurrentCursor;
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Create Database",
                                                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                         MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    tmpConn.Close();
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        private System.Windows.Forms.Cursor CurrentCursor;

        private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CurrentCursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current;
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor;

            ServerName = TBServerName.Text;

            ServerConnectionString = $"SERVER={ServerName}; DATABASE = master; User ID = sa; Pwd = { SAPassword.Text};";
            //ServerName = TBServerName.Text;
            //DataBaseName = TBDataBaseName.Text;
            connstr = $"Data Source={ServerName};Initial Catalog={DataBaseName}; User ID = sa; Pwd = { SAPassword.Text};";

            if (CreateDatabase() == false)
            {
                Close();
                return;
            }

            if (CreateTable("CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Battery] ( " +
                        "[BatteryId]            BIGINT     IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[CatalogNumber]        NCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Date]                 DATETIME   NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Description]          NCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[AuthorName]           NCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[IsLast]               BIT        NOT NULL, " +
                        "[SpecNum]              NCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[ATPNum]               NCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[ATPRev]               NCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[EngSpecNum]           NCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[EngSpecRev]           NCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[ProcessManagePlanNum] NCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[ProcessManagePlanRev] NCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[AcordToDwg]           NCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[AcordToDwgRev]        NCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[CustomerPortNum]      NCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[CustomerPortRev]      NCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[NumberOfOutput]       INT        NOT NULL, " +
                        "CONSTRAINT[PK__tmp_ms_x__5710805E59FA5E80] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([BatteryId] ASC));") == false)
            {
                Close();
                return;
            }

            if(CreateTable("CREATE TABLE[dbo].[Calibration]( " +
                "[MachineNumber]       INT      NOT NULL, " +
                "[LastCalibrationDate] DATETIME NOT NULL, " +
                "[NextCalibrationDate] DATETIME NOT NULL, " +
                "[NextReportNumber]    INT      NOT NULL, " +
                "[LastChange]          DATETIME DEFAULT(getdate()) NOT NULL, " +
                "PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([MachineNumber] ASC) " +
                ");") == false)
            {
                Close();
                return;
            }

            if(CreateTable("CREATE TABLE[dbo].[CatalogProp]( " +
                    "[CatalogNumber] NCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                    "[PropNumber]    INT        NOT NULL, " +
                    "[DateOfDefine]  DATETIME   NOT NULL, " +
                    "[Min]           FLOAT(53) NULL, " +
                    "[Max]           FLOAT(53) NULL, " +
                    "[IsLast]        BIT        NOT NULL, " +
                    "[MinMaxCode]    INT        NULL " +
                ");") == false)
            {
                Close();
                return;
            }

            if(CreateTable("CREATE TABLE[dbo].[CELL_Age]( " +
                        "[num]           INT         IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Teur_cell_age] NCHAR(100) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Code_age_cell] NCHAR(100) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[min_age]       BIGINT      NOT NULL, " +
                        "[max_age]       BIGINT      NOT NULL, " +
                        "[ocv_l]         FLOAT(53)  NOT NULL, " +
                        "[ocv_h]         FLOAT(53)  NOT NULL, " +
                        "[ccv_l]         FLOAT(53)  NOT NULL, " +
                        "[ccv_h]         FLOAT(53)  NOT NULL, " +
                        "[dV_l]          BIGINT      NOT NULL, " +
                        "[dV_h]          BIGINT      NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Department]    BIGINT      NOT NULL, " +
                        "[r_L]           BIGINT      NOT NULL, " +
                        "[r_H]           BIGINT      NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Change]        DATETIME    NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Active]        BIT         CONSTRAINT[DF__CELL_Age__Active__0E6E26BF] DEFAULT((1)) NOT NULL, " +
                        "CONSTRAINT[PK__CELL_Age__DF908D650C85DE4D] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([num] ASC));") == false)
            {
                Close();
                return;
            }

            if(CreateTable("CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ConnectionTable] ( " +
                        "[MacId]         NCHAR(20) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[ReportNumber]  BIGINT     NOT NULL, " +
                        "[CatalogNumber] NCHAR(11) NULL, " +
                        "[Date]          DATETIME   NULL, " +
                        "CONSTRAINT[PK__tmp_ms_x__B0E158BA02FC7413] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([MacId] ASC, [ReportNumber] ASC));") == false)
            {
                Close();
            }

            if(CreateTable("CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeliveryReport] ( " +
                        "[DeliveryNumber] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[SeriesNumber]   NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[CatalogNumber]  NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[ReportNumber]   NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[UserName]       NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[MACAddress]     NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[DataBaseName]   NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL);") == false)
            {
                Close();
                return;
            }

            if(CreateTable("CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HeaderResultPulser] ( " +
                        "[Id]                  BIGINT      IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[ReportNumber]        CHAR(255)  NOT NULL, " +
                        "[ReportDescription]   CHAR(255)  NOT NULL, " +
                        "[CatalogNumber]       NCHAR(255) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[WorkerName]          NCHAR(255) DEFAULT('') NOT NULL, " +
                        "[LastCalibrationDate] DATETIME    NOT NULL, " +
                        "[NextCalibrationDate] DATETIME    NOT NULL, " +
                        "[MachineNumber]       INT         NOT NULL, " +
                        "[EditTime]            DATETIME    NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Age]                 NCHAR(255) DEFAULT((1)) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Current]             INT         DEFAULT((-1)) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Time]                BIGINT      DEFAULT((-1)) NOT NULL, " +
                        "CONSTRAINT[PK_HeaderResultPulser] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([Id] ASC));") == false)
            {
                Close();
                return;
            }

            if(CreateTable("CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log] ( " +
                        "[DateTime] DATETIME       NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Location] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, " +
                        "[Value]    NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL);") == false)
            {
                Close();
                return;
            }

            if(CreateTable("CREATE TABLE[dbo].[LogDeliveryReport](" +
                        "[DateTime] DATETIME NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Location] TEXT     NULL, " +
                        "[Value]    TEXT     NULL);") == false)
            {
                Close();
                return;
            }

            if(CreateTable("CREATE TABLE[dbo].[Project](" +
                        "[num]               INT            IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Teur_Project]      NCHAR(100)    NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Code_Project]      NCHAR(100)    NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Code_age_cell]     NCHAR(100)    NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Current]           INT            NOT NULL, " +
                        "[time]              BIGINT         NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Cells_in_Parallel] INT            NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Cells_in_Series]   INT            NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Current_qc]        BIGINT         NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Time_QC]           BIGINT         NOT NULL, " +
                        "[dADocv_QC]         BIGINT         NOT NULL, " +
                        "[dAdccv_QC]         BIGINT         NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Department]        INT            NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Change]            DATETIME       NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Active]            BIT            CONSTRAINT[DF__Project__Active__151B244E] DEFAULT((1)) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[dADocv_min_text]   NVARCHAR(MAX) CONSTRAINT[DF__Project__dADocv___3493CFA7] DEFAULT('[]') NOT NULL, " +
                        "[dADocv_max_text]   NVARCHAR(MAX) CONSTRAINT[DF__Project__dADocv___3587F3E0] DEFAULT('[]') NOT NULL, " +
                        "[dADccv_min_text]   NVARCHAR(MAX) CONSTRAINT[DF__Project__dADccv___367C1819] DEFAULT('[]') NOT NULL, " +
                        "[dADccv_max_text]   NVARCHAR(MAX) CONSTRAINT[DF__Project__dADccv___37703C52] DEFAULT('[]') NOT NULL, " +
                        "CONSTRAINT[PK__Project__DF908D651332DBDC] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([num] ASC));") == false)
            {
                Close();
                return;
            }

            if(CreateTable("CREATE TABLE[dbo].[ProjectValuesChange](" +
                        "[OldReportNumber] NCHAR(255)   NOT NULL, " +
                        "[NewReportNumber] NCHAR(255)   NOT NULL, " +
                        "[WorkerName]      NCHAR(255)   NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Reason]          VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[OldOcvMin]       FLOAT(53)    NOT NULL, " +
                        "[OldOcvMax]       FLOAT(53)    NOT NULL, " +
                        "[OldCcvMin]       FLOAT(53)    NOT NULL, " +
                        "[OldCcvMax]       FLOAT(53)    NOT NULL, " +
                        "[OldDeltaMin]     INT           NOT NULL, " +
                        "[OldDeltaMax]     INT           NOT NULL, " +
                        "[OldTime]         INT           NOT NULL, " +
                        "[OldCurrent]      INT           NOT NULL, " +
                        "[NewOcvMin]       FLOAT(53)    NOT NULL, " +
                        "[NewOcvMax]       FLOAT(53)    NOT NULL, " +
                        "[NewCcvMin]       FLOAT(53)    NOT NULL, " +
                        "[NewCcvMax]       FLOAT(53)    NOT NULL, " +
                        "[NewDeltaMin]     INT           NOT NULL, " +
                        "[NewDeltaMax]     INT           NOT NULL, " +
                        "[NewTime]         INT           NOT NULL, " +
                        "[NewCurrent]      INT           NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Responsibility]  NCHAR(255)   NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Date]            DATETIME      NOT NULL);") == false)
            {
                Close();
                return;
            }

            if(CreateTable("CREATE TABLE[dbo].[Properties]( " +
                        "[PropNumber]  INT        NOT NULL, " +
                        "[PropName]    NCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[PropNameEn]  NCHAR(50) NULL, " +
                        "[OrderNumber] INT        NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Factory]     INT        NOT NULL, " +
                        "[IsLast]      BIT        NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Date]        DATETIME   NOT NULL );") == false)
            {
                Close();
                return;
            }

            if(CreateTable("CREATE TABLE[dbo].[PulserDescriptions](" +
                        "[PulserNumber] INT           NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Description]  VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Active]       BIT           DEFAULT((1)) NOT NULL, "+
                        "PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([PulserNumber] ASC));") == false)
            {
                Close();
                return;
            }

            if(CreateTable("CREATE TABLE[dbo].[ResultPulser]( " +
                        "[Id]           BIGINT     IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[ReportNumber] CHAR(255) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[BatchNumber]  CHAR(255) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[DateTime]     DATETIME   NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Ocv]          FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[OcvMin]       FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[OcvMax]       FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Ccv]          FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[CcvMin]       FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[CcvMax]       FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Delta]        BIGINT     NOT NULL, " +
                        "[DeltaMin]     BIGINT     NOT NULL, " +
                        "[DeltaMax]     BIGINT     NOT NULL, " +
                        "[NumberInTest] INT        NOT NULL);") == false)
            {
                Close();
                return;
            }

            if(CreateTable("CREATE TABLE[dbo].[ResultPulserQA](" +
                        "[Id]           BIGINT     IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[ReportNumber] CHAR(255) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[BatchNumber]  CHAR(255) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[DateTime]     DATETIME   NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Ocv]          FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[OcvMin]       FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[OcvMax]       FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Ccv]          FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[CcvMin]       FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[CcvMax]       FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Delta]        BIGINT     NOT NULL, " +
                        "[DeltaMin]     BIGINT     NOT NULL, " +
                        "[DeltaMax]     BIGINT     NOT NULL, " +
                        "[NumberInTest] INT        NOT NULL);") == false)
            {
                Close();
                return;
            }

            if(CreateTable("CREATE TABLE[dbo].[ResultReport](" +
                        "[Obj]          TEXT   NULL, " +
                        "[ReportNumber] BIGINT NOT NULL);") == false)
            {
                Close();
                return;
            }

            if(CreateTable("CREATE TABLE[dbo].[Results](" +
                        "[ResultId]          BIGINT     IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Ocv]               FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Ccv]               FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Delta]             FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[FOcv]              NCHAR(1)  NOT NULL, " +
                        "[FCcv]              NCHAR(1)  NOT NULL, " +
                        "[FDelta]            NCHAR(1)  NOT NULL, " +
                        "[BatchNumber]       NCHAR(10) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[CellOfTestCounter] INT        NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Time]              DATETIME   NOT NULL, " +
                        "[ReportNumber]      BIGINT     NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Output]            INT        NOT NULL, " +
                        "[CatalogNumber]     NCHAR(20) NULL );") == false)
            {
                Close();
                return;
            }

            if(CreateTable("CREATE TABLE[dbo].[TestBattery](" +
                        "[CatalogNumber] CHAR(50)  NOT NULL, " +
                        "[OcvMin]        FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[OcvMax]        FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[CcvMin]        FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[CcvMax]        FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " +
                        "[DeltaMin]      BIGINT     NOT NULL, " +
                        "[DeltaMax]      BIGINT     NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Time]          BIGINT     NOT NULL, " +
                        "[Current]       INT        NOT NULL, " +
                        "PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([CatalogNumber] ASC));") == false)
            {
                Close();
                return;
            }

            if(CreateTable("CREATE TABLE[dbo].[TestParams](" +
                        "[MACAddress]     NCHAR(256)    NOT NULL, " +
                        "[DeliveryNumber] NCHAR(256)    NOT NULL, " +
                        "[UserName]       NCHAR(256)    NOT NULL, " +
                        "[PoTadiran]      NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL );") == false)
            {
                Close();
                return;
            }

            if(CreateTable("CREATE TABLE[dbo].[WorkerNames](" +
                        "[Name] NCHAR(50) NOT NULL);") == false)
            {
                Close();
                return;
            }
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = CurrentCursor;
            MessageBox.Show("Database and tables creation has been sucsessfull");
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Two comments / recommendations: **(1)** if you have the complete SQL create script - why not just add that SQL to your project as an "embedded resource", load it, and execute it (the whole script at once) against your new machine? Or **(2)** - couldn't you read the structure of the existing database (at runtime) and just apply that structure to the new database? Doing it with all those `CreateTable` calls seems overly complicated and messy......

Comment: And what about other database objects such as views and stored procedures? Maintaining a create script for the entire database inside the c# code seems to me like an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: If you have access to a user that is a member of the sysadmin role, you can use [`DBCC CLONEDATABASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-clonedatabase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#permissions)

Comment: this is why Entity Framework is useful. I recommend to use it, and maintain your database from the code.

Comment: Can you simply restore a backup of the source database instead of jumping through hoops? Also if you can I would suggest you convert your Char and NChar to Varchar and NVarchar

Comment: @MarkKram backup & restore will also copy all the data. That can be deleted, of course, but at a cost. As for changing `char` to `nchar` - why? if a column is designed to only contain chars within the ascii range, why use `nchar`?

Comment: Not if you create a backup of an empty database 

Comment: @MarkKram back up and restore might be a viable option if you can empty the target database, not the source database. but to do that you would need to delete the data in the correct order (referencing tables before referenced tables) and to get the correct order you would either have to store and maintain a static SQL file containing the deletes (and not forget to update it any time the database structure changes) or write the delete / truncate script dynamically, which can be done but much harder.

Comment: I have an empty database that I use for this exact situation. I wouldn't think it would take much effort to empty the database considering that you are acquainted with it's structure. If not then you could use SSMS to script the database without data and only fill those tables that may need data .

Comment: I just found this great PowerShell script that will build out a DDL for the entire database including all objects: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/automated-script-generation-with-powershell-and-smo/

Comment: Here is a niffty SProc that will do the same thing: http://www.stormrage.com/SQLStuff/sp_GetDDLa_Latest.txt